# Java Stream group by a field and order by this field count?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stream, java-stream

I am trying to get countryCode of the 3 countries that has max cities by usimng Java Stream on the following entity:

***City:***

```
id   | name     | countryCode |
------------------------------
1    | Berlin   | DE          |
2    | Munich   | DE          |
3    | Köln     | DE          |
4    | Paris    | FR          |
5    | Kopenhag | DK          |
...
```

I tried something, but not working as expected. So, what is the most proper way to get top 3 country code (top 3 mostly repeated country code)?

```
final Map<String, City> airportCodes2 = airportService.getCities().stream()
                .map(City::getCountryCode, Function.identity())
                .toMap();
```

Comment: @Chaosfire Not actually, I want to get the 3 countries that has the most cities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sorting

The simplest approach would be to group the data by `countryCode` by generating an auxiliary map of type `Map<String, Long>`, associating each `countryCode` with the count of cities.

Then generate a stream over the map entries and sort it in the reverse order by *Value* (*i.e. in Descending order of the city count*).

That how it might be implemented:

```
public static List<String> getTopNCodes(List<City> cities,
                                        int limit) {
    return cities.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( // creates a Map<String, Long>
            City::getCountryCode,
            Collectors.counting()
        ))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .limit(limit) // <- retain top N
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .toList();
}
```

Time complexity of this approach is **O(n * log n)** doe to sorting, which would be downside would be if number of elements to retrieve it small (like `3`), meanwhile the data is massive.

We can do better.

## Partial sorting using Custom Collector

Instead of sorting all entries of the auxiliary map, we can perform partial sorting using `PriorityQueue` (this class is an implementation of the *Binary Heap* offered by JDK).

For that, we can implement a custom collector using static factory method `Collector.of()`.

An instance of `PriorityQueue` would be used as a mutable container of the Collector. Each map entry from the stream would be compared with the *root* element of the Heap. If the element is greater (entry holds a larger count) the next entry gets added to the queue root. And in case if the limit is exceeded, the root element should be removed.

To make the code reusable we can gentrify it. The first part (creating an intermediate map with Values representing frequencies of Keys) remains the same.

```
public static <T, K> List<K> getTopN(List<T> list,
                                          Function<T, K> keyExtractor,
                                          int limit) {
    return list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            keyExtractor,
            Collectors.counting()
        ))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(getMaxN(
            limit,
            Map.Entry.<K, Long>comparingByValue().reversed(),
            Map.Entry::getKey
        ));
}
```

Min Heap-based Collector:

```
public static <T, R> Collector<T, ?, List<R>> getMaxN(int size,
                                                      Comparator<T> comparator,
                                                      Function<T, R> keyExtractor) {
    
    return Collector.of(
        () -> new PriorityQueue<>(comparator),
        (Queue<T> queue, T next) -> tryAdd(queue, next, comparator, size),
        (Queue<T> left, Queue<T> right) -> {
            right.forEach(next -> tryAdd(left, next, comparator, size));
            return left;
        },
        (Queue<T> queue) -> queue.stream().map(keyExtractor).toList(),
        Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED
    );
}

public static <T> void tryAdd(Queue<T> queue, T next, Comparator<T> comparator, int size) {
    if (queue.size() == size && comparator.compare(queue.element(), next) < 0)
        queue.remove(); // if next value is greater than the smallest element in the queue and max size has been exceeded the smallest element needs to be removed from the queue
    if (queue.size() < size) queue.add(next);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up, it would probably solve the problem. Just a question; I am using OpenCSV and actually think of create such a kind of filtering and mapping the result. But is "fetching the data and getting result by using Java Stream is a better way?" I just thought to filter the necessary records while reading CSV rows, but not sure if it would be possible by OpenCSV (I could not find a similar example). Any idea?

Comment: @gonzales Short answer: if performance matters, you need to measure it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. At the last step I am trying to use these country codes to get cities (I can just use these codes to retrieve cities as there is no FK other than codes). So, in this scene, should I use `ParallelStream` or `CompletableFuture`? (if there is database, I would merge the data on Database side, but for this, I read data from multiple CSV files). Any idea?

Comment: I mean do you have any idea for this separate question? >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74551863/java-stream-merging-multiple-results-read-from-separate-csv-files

Comment: @gonzales There are many things mixed together. CSV-files and Database. If you have a Database and you have to process a large amount of data, the sure it's better to process it on the database side and retrieve only a small portion. If you're forced to do heavy computations (something CPU-intensive operations), you can make use then you can make use of the parallel streams. On the other hand, `ComplitableFuture` is a tool which is focused on arranging asynchronous execution, if you not performing a number-crunching task but calling something - go with a ComplitableFuture.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful explanations. There is some points that I need to inform you. Could you please clarify me about them? >>>

Comment: **1.**  I don't have a database and read data from multiple CSV files. I think there is no need to use a database just for reading these CSV files. Because the data may be changed and each time I will need to read the CSV files even if the previously read data had been saved to the database. Is that right?

Comment: **2.** I can use parallel streams or ComplitableFuture maybe. **BUT**, I need to use the result of first query in my second query as a parameter. So, in this case, should I still use these methods? Or should I use a different approach in Java Stream?

Comment: You may share your next suggestion for this question on that page (except from the last 2 questions): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74551863/java-stream-merging-multiple-results-read-from-separate-csv-files?noredirect=1#comment131600372_74551863

Comment: @gonzales I've mentioned database only because you've mentioned it. *"I need to use the result of first query in my second query as a parameter."* that means that these operations should be performed sequentially, one after another. You can chain these steps using `CompletableFuture`. Since is primarily focused on code, a code-attempt (or description in pseudocode of how dialing with files), would bring value to the linked question.

Comment: I will try `CompletableFuture` and hope it solves my problem. On the other hand,I think there is never need to use database for reading CSV data, right?

Comment: @gonzales If you're fine with storing data as CSV files, you don't need a DB. If you have some doubts, you can ask on https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com. It would be more suitable for these site then for SO, since it's an architectural problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these useful helps. Actually I just need to read data, not need to write. For this reason, I think no need to use database. However, I am wondering if I need to use a text file, etc. to keep the read data temporarily instead of using Buffered Memory during csv file read. Any idea for that?